# On the meaning of 'to not commit to a meeting' in this context

Tags: sentence-meaning

The following passage was taken from this [NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/10/14/us/politics/bolton-giuliani-fiona-hill-testimony.html?action=click&module=Top%20Stories&pgtype=Homepage) (7th, 8th, and 9th paragraph counting from the last paragraph).

> One of the most dramatic moments she described came in the July 10 meeting in Mr. Bolton’s office that included Mr. Sondland; Kurt D. Volker, then the special envoy for Ukraine; Rick Perry, the energy secretary; and two Ukrainian officials.
>
> The purpose of the meeting was to talk about technical assistance to Ukraine’s national security council. *The Ukrainians were eager to set up a meeting* between Mr. Trump and Mr. Zelensky, who was elected on a promise to clean up corruption and resolve the country’s five-year war with Russian-armed separatists.
>
> **Mr. Bolton was trying to not commit to a meeting**, according to Ms. Hill’s testimony. Mr. Sondland got agitated, Ms. Hill testified, and let out that there was an agreement with Mr. Mulvaney that there would be a meeting if Ukraine opened up the investigations the White House was seeking.

Does the sentence in bold mean Bolton was trying to *avoid* (not appear at) the meeting the Ukrainians wanted, or that he was trying to prevent the meeting from happening?

Answer (score 1):

In context, the Ukrainian team and the US team were discussing setting up a meeting with their leaders. Bolton was attempting to avoid agreeing to setup this meeting between the US president and the Ukrainian president.

Answer (score 1):

In this context:

> [**Commit**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/commit) means to promise to give yourself, your money, your time, etc., to support something

So essentially Mr Bolton does not want to *promise* that he will have this meeting. He can be described as *non-committal*.

I think, given this definition, it is fair to say he is probably trying to avoid the meeting, but that is sub-textual.